# kivy: cambiar color de un label

Tags: python, kivy, color

sea el siguiente código en python:

```
# config
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'system')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

    def showquestion(self):
        with open("question.txt","r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['label1'].text = filetext

    def showanswer(self):
        with open("answer.txt","r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['label2'].text = filetext


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()
    def on_pause(self): 
        return True
    def on_resume(self): 
        pass


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'): 
    myApp().run()
```

Y el siguiente código en .kv:

```
<MyWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size

        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Mostrar respuesta"
            on_release: root.showanswer()
            size_hint: 1, 0.1

        Button:
            id: button2
            text: "Pregunta Acertada"
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
        Button:
            id: button3
            text: "Pregunta Fallada"
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
        Button:
            id: button4
            text: "mostrar pregunta"
            on_release: root.showquestion()
            size_hint: 1, 0.1

#label1 muestra la pregunta
        Label:
            id: label1
            color: 1,0,1,1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:  0, 0, 0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
#label2 muestra la respuesta        
        Label:
            id: label2
            background_color: 1,0,1,0
```

Quisiera poner el label1 naranja y el label2 verde.
He buscado en stackoverflow en ingles, y he encontrado [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460952/kivy-press-button-change-color-of-a-label).
Pero yo lo quiero hacer desde el propio fichero .kv y no pasando por el fichero .py
En el label1 lo que he conseguido cambiar son el color de las letras.
Mientras que en el label2 parece ignorar la etiqueta "background_color".
Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay dos aspectos a tener en cuenta:

- Para cambiar el color del texto del `Label` se usa el atributo `color` como haces tú en tu `label1`.
- Para cambiar el color de fondo no se usa `background_color` ya que este atributo no existe por defecto para la gran mayoría de widgets. En su lugar se usa un `canvas` tal y como haces tu en `label1`.

Relacionado con esto hay otros dos aspectos importantes:

- Un `Canvas` en Kivy no es un witget sobre el que dibujar. Es un error muy común al empezar en kivy porque resulta ambiguo el nombre. En otros frameworks un 'canvas' es eso mismo, un lienzo sobre el que dibujar cosas, por ejemplo en Tkinter o en HTML5.

  En Kivy un `Canvas` es más como un contenedor de instrucciones que nos dice como dibujar sobre otro widget. Contiene instrucciones para pintar, no es una superficie sobre la que pintar. Digamos que es algo así como una caja de lápices y no una hoja de papel, contiene las herramientas para pintar.
- Otro problema común es el uso de los atributos `rgb` y `rgba`. En kivy los valores rgb son floats de 0 a 1 y no enteros de 0 a 255 como solemos usar a menudo. Dado que la gran mayoría de mortales no conocemos el valor rgb de todos los colores usamos tablas o [herramientas online](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Colors/Herramienta_para_seleccionar_color) que nos dan los valores rgb de un color. Para pasar el color a valores apropiados para kivy simplemente hay que dividir cada canal entre 255. Recuerda que rgba usa además de los valores para el rojo, verde y azul el valor alpha que define la transparencia (1 es ninguna transparencia y 0 es transparencia total, por lo que no verás color alguno sino el fondo de detrás del widget).

  Por ejemplo, un tono de naranja con algo de transparencia sería:

  ```
  rgba(173, 120, 40, 0.8)
  ```

  En kivy debe ser:

  ```
  rgba(173/255, 120/255, 40/255, 0.8)
  ```

Tus Labels deberian quedar definidos algo así:

```
#label1 muestra la pregunta
        Label:
            id: label1
            color: 1,0,1,1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 191/255.0, 144/255.0, 63/255.0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos

#label2 muestra la respuesta
        Label:
            id: label2
            color: 1,0,1,1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:  110/255.0, 191/255.0, 63/255.0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size: self.size
```

**Nota Importante:** Observa que uso `110/255.0` y no `110/255`, esto es para permitir la compatibilidad con Python 2 y por tanto con Android. En Python 3 el operador de división siempre retorna un `float`. En Python 2 el tipo retornado depende de los tipos de entrada (en este caso dos enteros), si hacemos  `110/255` retorna un entero, es decir, nos da la división entera de 110/255 que es 0. Al usar `255.0` forzamos a que retorne un `float` (0.4313...). De no hacer esto, en Python 2, siempre obtendremos un fondo negro (`0,0,0,1`).

Creo que para lo que estas intentando será mejor que cambies de contenedor principal, un `BoxLayout` no parece lo mejor. Mirate las distintas opciones en la [documentación](https://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/layouts.html) y recuerda que se pueden combinar unos dentro de otros sin problemas. El que más libertad (y más trabajo) da es el FloatLayout, todo depende de la estructura que quieras que tenga tu app al final. Si por ahora solo estas experimentando con la lógica y los widget de tu app sigue con el BoxLayout y preocupate de esto al final.

Comment: ¿Así que tengo que usar "canvas" a la fuerza, para poder darle color a un label en un .kv?

Comment: Si, tanto si usas kivy languaje o lo haces directamente en Python  en el `main.py` tienes que usar `canvas`, eso da igual. Es la forma en la que funciona Kivy en este aspecto. Como digo el Canvas no es un lienzo, son instrucciones para dibujar sobre un widget. No es que crees un Canvas dentro del Label y colorees el Canvas, sino que Canvas permite colorear al Label. Se que es confuso sobretodo si se viene de otros frameworks en los que el Canvas es una superficie de dibujo. Puedes mirar la documentación [aqui](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html).